# Adjust web.config file for axios requests

Tags: vue.js, iis, axios, web-config

I have a web.config file on Azure as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is required, as per [documents](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) as I am using Vue.js in history mode.
Now, my Vue makes requests to a backend using Axios and this webconfig breaks these calls.
Here is an example call:

```
axios.get(`${url}foo/${item.barID}`, {
          params
        })
```

Which works when the web.config is absent but not when it is present (likely as I have a number going in after foo for my specific GET request).
How can I edit my web.config to allow this particular rule, and in general other axios calls (PATCH,PUT,DELETE) where an id appears after the / (i.e. axios.get(url/foo/3)
This application will not be changed much when running so I dont mind hardcoding the 10 or so calls that are breaking.

Sorry, I dont really understand how the web.config works so any help would be great!

Comment: Use FRT to learn more, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and then you might adjust the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I dont think this will help as the requests are not actually failing, instead they are serving me the Vue.js index.html, rather than the expected HTTP response. So for example axios.get(www.example.com/foo/2) fails but axios.get(www.example.com/bar) will return expected JSON. I need someway of telling web.config to ignore specific request URL requests rather than rewriting them

Comment: "I dont really understand how the web.config works", and that's what FRT can teach you on. Without that knowledge, I don't think you can easily move further and help yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your response! I though you were saying to do Failed Request Trace on Azure. I will go through the tutorial see if I can figure it out and get back, thanks